# Get data from fragments inside viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a FRAGMENT with a viewpager with 7 other fragments. These fragments are used to enter user details. In the final fragment, there is a "submit" button where I need to get all the user details entered in the other fragments. How can I do this

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39024962/get-data-from-viewpager-fragments) question which didnt help. So please dont mark this question duplicate.

**The base fragment**:

```
public class Register_Layout extends Fragment implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{
public Register_Layout(){}

static ViewPager viewPager1;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register_layout,  container, false);

    viewPager1 = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager1);
    viewPager1.setOffscreenPageLimit(7);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager =  getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    viewPager1.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmentManager));

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int    positionOffsetPixels) {

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {

}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

}

}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    if(position==0)
    {
        fragment = new Register();
    }

    if(position==1)
    {
        fragment = new Register_Page2();
    }

    if(position==2)
    {
        fragment = new Register_Page3();
    }

    if(position==3)
    {
        fragment = new Register_Page4();
    }

    if(position==4)
    {
        fragment = new Register_Page5();
    }

    if(position==5)
    {
        fragment = new Register_Page6();
    }

    if(position==6)
    {
        fragment = new Register_Page7();
    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 7;
}
}
```

**The final fragment where I should get data of all other fragments:**

```
public class Register_Page7 extends Fragment {
public Register_Page7(){

}

EditText editText;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register_page7, container, false);

    Button Previous = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Previous7);
    Button Regiter = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Submit);
    Regiter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to submit?");

            alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                }
            });
            alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No,Let me check the details again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                }
            });

            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });

    Previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new Register_Layout().viewPager1.setCurrentItem(5);

        }
    });
    return view;
  }
 }
```

Comment: It would be nice to see the code. Maybe how you are instantiating the fragments initially.

Comment: hold on a second @RyanAlford

Comment: you can create a temp array or other data structure in your Activity and store the data using interface callbacks

Comment: @RyanAlford: I have added the code. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to use the fragment manager to get all of the instantiated fragments, and loop through them to get their relevant data.

You could create a subclass of `Fragment` that all of the fragments would inherit from. This subclass would have a `getText` method(or some other type of public method), that gets the text from the `EditText` view.

For other types of data(like switches), you would have similar functions to get the data from the fragment.

**Edited**

So you could create a new fragment that is derived from `Fragment`.

```
public class BaseEntryFragment extends Fragment {
    public BaseEntryFragment() {}

    public String getEntryText() {}
}
```

Then you take your existing fragments and extend your new fragment..

```
public class Register_Page7 extends BaseEntryFragment {

    private EditText _editText;

    public Register_Page7() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //other create view code
        _editText = (EditText)FindViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    }

    @Override
    public String getEntryText() {
        return _editText.getText();
    }
}
```

Then with your submit..

```
List<Fragment> fragments = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
for(Fragment frag : fragments) {
    // do type checks here
    BaseEntryFragment f = (BaseEntryFragment)frag;
    String someValue = f.getEntryText();
}
```

Please note, my Java is really really rusty, so it may not be the perfect syntax. This is just some code to get you started and not intended to be copied and pasted.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? Sorry I'm new to android. I cant understand everything that you say. Please help

Answer (score 0):

i think it is easier in each fragment, you store the user data on a SharedPreference (the data structure can be a json string or whatever you like), at the end (last fragment) read the shared pref data, and perform the register

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use an `Activity` to hold your `ViewPager` and declare there the variables or objects you want to save from `Fragments`.

In each `Fragment` you want to save data you have to use `interface` to pass the data to the `Activity`. Here is the way to do it: [Passing data between a fragment and its container activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9977370/5097932)

Then in your last `Fragment` you can call (with generated getters for the variables I mentioned before) to your container `Activity` like this:

```
YourActivity yourActivity = ((YourActivity) getActivity());
int foo = yourActivity.getFooInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find fragments in your Activity and get data from each fragment by public method. Variable `position` is position of fragment in your viewpager

```
public Fragment getFragment(ViewPager container, int position) {
String name = makeFragmentName(container.getId(), position);
return  mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(name);
}

private static String makeFragmentName(int viewId, int index) {
    return "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + index;
}
```